# Wait for multiline console input to finish c#

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am supposed to write a program where the user inputs a maze and my application tries to find a way to navigate through it. The input of the maze is supposed to be something like

```
#####
#...#
#...#
#####
```

And I am supposed to use Console.OpenStandardInput(), and the user copy pastes the maze into the console. However, when I use Console.ReadLine() to wait for the user to copy paste the maze, it only reads the first line. I know for Java you just make a new Scanner(System.in), but how do I do this in c#?

EDIT:
My entire code is

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write((char)sr.Read());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I copy and paste in

AB

CD

From Notepad, the output becomes

AB

AB

CDcursor here

Comment: Is there any problem in my answer? If there is, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() return after every single line so you need to use loop to read all line from console till you will get null

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Either you do here something with each line separately or
    lines.add(line);
}
// You do something with all of the lines here
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use Console.OpenStandardInput()